# Flutter app name wrong in the switching app view of Xiomi Mi 8

Tags: android, flutter

Wrong app name while switching app screen

[This image shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD2Ni.png)

My cell phone is a **Xiomi Mi 8**.

I am setting `android:label="Gerenciador de Tempo` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file; The app name on the all apps screen is correct:

[Correct app name in the main all apps screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzw4R.jpg)

Can anyone light me on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the title of your Material App to the one you want.

For exemple :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Gerenciador de Tempo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change "title" of main Widget 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my "problem".